# Find the rate for given date from mysql table

Tags: mysql, date

I have a table:

```
adate                pdt_id      pdt_rate
2017-10-02           5           20
2017-10-05           5           25
2017-10-07           5           23
2017-10-11           5           20
```

I have to find the `rate` of product with `pdt_id` 5 for **between dates 2017-10-01 and 2017-10-10**

For 2017-10-01 there is no rate in table so I take the lesser date like 2017-09-30 (no record), 2017-09-29 (no record) and so on (unfortunately no record). So I turn the bigger date than 2017-10-01 is 2017-10-02 (yes, there is a record) so I stop the searching and finalize as

```
2017-10-01  rate is 20
```

Now find the next date 2017-10-02, there is record and is 20

```
2017-10-02  rate is 20
```

Following the similar criteria I got

```
2017-10-03 rate is  20
2017-10-04 rate is  20
2017-10-05 rate is  25
....
2017-10-10 rate is  23
```

So my question is How to **Find the rate for given date if the date exist other wise take the rate of lesser date and if the lesser date is not exist find the rate of next bigger date**?

**Finally we get rate for all dates(from start date to end date).**

How can I achieve this?

```
$begin = new DateTime('2017-10-01');
$end = new DateTime('2017-10-10');

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
   $dateval = $date->format("Y-m-d");
   // here I want find the rate for each date
}
```

Comment: Is this question about writing PHP or MySQL code? You used both tags.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski, `mysql query`. I removed the PHP tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (adate <= '2017-10-01') desc
         abs(datediff(adate, '2017-10-01'))
limit 1;
```